# Cant Defer or Delay ColdFusion.navigate() , ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion, chaining

Maybe there is something screwy with Coldfusion's Ajax functions, but I cant figure this one out... Im just trying to post some data using `ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm`, then load new content into `#CartPopup` using `ColdFusion.navigate`. I need `Details.cfm` to finish processing the form data before I load the `Div`.

```
function add2Cart(prodid){
    var submit = ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm('AddToCart', 'Details.cfm');
    setTimeout("navigate(prodid)", 2000);
}

function navigate(prodid){
    ColdFusion.navigate('divbind.cfm?PRODID='+ prodid,'CartPopup','CB','EH');
    return false;   
}
```

Do perhaps a delay isn't the best way.  I thought of using:

```
jQuery.when
```

but I'm wondering if maybe my issue if with the CF ajax functions... I'm super grateful for any insight or alternative approaches.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first snippet of code should be:

```
function add2Cart(prodid){
    ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm(
        'AddToCart',
        'Details.cfm',
        function() { navigate(prodid); },
        function() { alert('Error happened - form was not submitted'); }
   );
}
```

As you can see [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=JavaScriptFcns_03.html) `submitForm` can receive 2 callback handlers, one when the submit is done and one for error handling.

Comment: Thanks, that worked great.  Also i needed to onsubmit= "return false;" for onsubmit of my form,  Else it was refreshing the page.